# Can a SQL Server connection be reused on two different concurrent requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-pooling

Our setup is ASP.NET MVC using Ninject and we instantiate and open a new connection on a per request basis using the same connection string every time. Based on this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) Connection Pooling will reuse connections, but I am wondering if it's possible for a connection in used on one request to be reused on a concurrent request at the same exact time.

The reason for this question is we have a query where we set the `ISOLATION LEVEL` to `READ UNCOMMITTED` run the query and then set it back to what it was. Since setting the `ISOLATION LEVEL` is at the connection level we are wondering if it's possible for other requests to be reading "dirty" data during the time frame when the ISOLATION was `READ UNCOMMITTED`.

Comment: As far as I understand, a *single connection* from the ADO.NET connection pool can **never** be used in two concurrent requests - once it's taken from the pool by one request to be used - it's gone, no other request could ever get that same connection for his work

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a connection is placed back into the pool, it is reset via a call to *sp_reset_connection*. Unfortunately, it does NOT affect the isolation level.

There are complaints about this behavior here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/243527/sp-reset-connection-doesnt-reset-isolation-level

If you must change the isolation level, I'm afraid you'll need to:

- Explicitly set isolation level on every query
- Use a different connection string (preferably with pooling disabled) when changing isolation level
- Move isolation level changes into stored procedures